# Creating a new component in microcap12

Tags: module

I am using microcap12 and created my own 2-input AND gate using 6 Mos-FET. I want to add it as a new component to the digital primitives library but fail when following the "Adding new part wizard".
If someone did it - I would love to get the details of how to add a new module to the Microcap libarary.

Comment: Not sure you can add components to micro-cap any primitives list. Maybe show the procedure you took with a series of screen shots.